# Macro / vba script to create Outlook Connection status reconnect button in ribbon

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I am looking if it is possible to create a Reconnect button for the Reconnect function usually invoked by checking the Outlook Connection Status.

It would help me a lot to not have to open this dialogue but to just press Reconnect immediately from a button on the Ribbon.

Reason: We seem to have a lot of performance issues (O365) at our Management assistants. We also notice a reconnect gives them air.

I know this is not a solution but at least a workaround for the problems at hand.

Many thanks!

Mike